# Angular2 Selectioning an element with a ngIf on it

Tags: angular

Here is my html :

```
<div id="foo" (mouseover)="blah()" *ngIf="isDisplayed"></div>
```

And my js :

```
isDisplayed: boolean = false
blah() {
  this.isDisplayed = true
  console.log(document.getElementById('foo'))
}
```

However, my console.log does print null.
If I add a `setTimeout` around the `console.log`, it works but that's hacky and will be a mess when several events will be in play. I mean, I do get that the `getElementById` is run before the template's `ngIf` gets updated. How could I be sure that the template is updated when running my `console.log`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Invoke change detection explicitly then Angular will update the DOM immediately.

```
constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {}

isDisplayed: boolean = false
blah() {
  this.isDisplayed = true;
  this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  console.log(document.getElementById('foo'));
}
```

Comment: Cheers mate ! I actually thought about it, but for some reasons I didn't try it